# dos2unix command

Tags: linux, sh, dos2unix

I have this script

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `ls -R`
do
  echo "Changing $i"
  fromdos $i 
done
```

I want to remove "^M" charcaters from many files which are in more subdirectories. I got this:

```
fromdos: Unable to access file
```

Is there somethig i'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The variable $orig is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't need a *for* loop.

Here is a quick panorama of solutions for files with extension ".ext" (such commands shall be somehow restrictive)

note : ^M is obtained with CTRL-V" + "CTRL-M"

```
# PORTABLE SOLUTION 
find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -exec sed -i -e 's/^M$//' {} \;

# GNU-sed
find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -exec sed -i -e "s/\x0D$//g" {} \;

# SED with more recent nux
find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -exec sed -i -e "s/\r$//g" {} \;

# DOS2UNIX
find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | while read -r -d "$(printf "\000")" -r path; do dos2unix $path $path"_new"; done

# AWK
 find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | while read -r -d "$(printf "\000")" -r path; do awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' $path > $path"_new"; done

# TR
 find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -print0 | while read -r -d "$(printf "\000")" -r path; do cat $path | tr -d '\r' > $path"_new"; done

# PERL
 find /home -type f -name "*.ext" -exec perl -pi -e 's/\r//g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

`ls -R` lists everything, including directories. So you're telling `fromdos` to act on actual directories is some cases.

Try something like this:

```
find . -type f -exec fromdos {} \;
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you'd hit the little 'accept answer' button, I'd be very grateful :-)

Comment: adding path to find would be nice :-)

Comment: @hornetbzz Sorry, the `find` variant I usually use doesn't require it, so I rarely pass it.

Comment: thx for the edit. I added the comment as I experienced a similar bad use of find/rm, as this may happen to everbody if not explicit :-)